# AlmoFire and Swift 4

Tags: rest, api, alamofire, swift4

I have been using Almofire for many of my projects. Today I read an article on Swift4 encoder and decoder. Could you put some points for me If I should continue using Almofire for my next IOS App which I will be starting out in the next one week. I would appreciate your response.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.
please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your queries.

Comment: Thank you. Was anticipating a useful response.